# Do any results rely on the boundedess of the empty set

Tags: real-analysis

I understand the boundedness of the empty set is "vacuously true". I'm struggling to distinguish this concept from "meaningless" or "absurd", and I'm curious to know if any results depend on this proposition.

Comment: "Uninteresting" is different from "absurd:" vacuous truths are perfectly meaningful, they're just utterly boring. (It may help to think of their double negations: "Every element of the emptyset is a unicorn" is equivalent to "There is no element of the emptyset with the not-a-unicorn property," and the latter is clearly meaningful - if totally silly.) If we adopted a system of logic which didn't permit them, a lot of theorems would have to have the word "nonempty" added all over the place. And there's no obvious reason to make that change.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Wikipedia has "In mathematics and logic, a vacuous truth is a conditional or universal statement that is only true because the antecedent cannot be satisfied". As I understand it, that's how the boundedness of the empty set is proved. On that basis, can we avoid the conclusion that $\emptyset$ is bounded below by $1$ and bounded above by $0$, and therefore that a lower bound can be strictly greater than an upper bound? That's the sort of thing that makes me suspect vacuous truths might be either meaningless or absurd.

Answer (score 3):

A subset of a bounded set is bounded.  (False unless $\varnothing$ is bounded.)

Comment: Does anything rely on that?

Comment: You'd have to amend many basic statements. For example, "a *nonempty* subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded." Ultimately the math wouldn't change, you might just have to add a few extra words to many statements. Mathematicians hate a few extra words.